# Would "to avoid the class/set distinction" be, or not be, an ad hoc reason to propose a couniversal set?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, set-theory, explanation

Once upon a time, von Neumann proposed the [axiom of limitation-of-size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size), which says that any class "too large to be a set" is then a "proper class," meaning that there is a distinction between proper classes and proper sets. Weird wiggle-arounds of this concept include the notion of [semisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiset), but anyway, the condition "too large to be a set" can often enough be traced to issues surrounding Russell's paradox.

Now unfortunately, however, if we assume von Neumann's axiom, it quickly follows that |ORD| = |CARD|, and all proper classes are the *same* "size" ("absolutely infinite"), wherefore the well-ordering lemma and even global choice follow, too (see [Hamkins[??]](https://jdh.hamkins.org/the-global-choice-principle-in-godel-bernays-set-theory/) for the details). Although for silly moralistic reasons, I am drawn towards proofs of global choice/well-ordering, I am also fond of [amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) and would prefer to be able to say that |AMORPHOUS| is *incommensurate with* |ORD|, wherefore |CARD| is beyond either (since it subsumes both, as well as |COAMORPHOUS|, e.g. the choiceless Continuum, which I assume exists (alongside the well-orderable one) because of the background independence of ∃℘(ℵ<sub>0</sub>) on **AC**<sup>**AR**</sup>).

But then I'd really like to avoid the class/set distinction altogether. **Inasmuch as the couniversal-set approach to Russell's paradox (a well-founded set of all and only *other* well-founded sets) is compatible with the omission of the class/set distinction, is appealing to the possibility of that omission sufficient to render an appeal to a couniversal set no longer *ad hoc* (as a solution to Russell's paradox)?** As Conifold mentioned in a comment to a related question of mine, here, positing a couniversal set "merely" to avoid Russell's paradox (or salvage almost all naive comprehension) comes across as an *ad hoc*/non-principled approach to the issue. And though as the issue evaporates into the oblivion of absolute infinity, the *ad hoc*/not *ad hoc* distinction itself seems to slowly dissolve, yet it would be "nice" to preserve our theoretical commitments (commitments to finding general principles first and invoking particular exceptions only when unavoidably "necessary") even so, "for as long as possible."

---

<sup>**AR**</sup>Since the powerset axiom is also independent on the axiom scheme of replacement, I assume that the "real" cardinality of the Continuum can be that only of an infinite set that exists below, or apart from, ℵ<sub>ω</sub>.

Comment: I recommend to move this question to https://mathoverflow.net/.  At most, I see a possible relation to philosophy with the term "ad hoc/not ad hoc" distinction. But even this term remains unclear in your question, also to which of Conifold's comments you refer.

Comment: @JoWehler is there any way to migrate the question from here to there? Every time I vote to migrate a question from this SE, it only gives the option of doing so to the PhilosophySE Meta, which never seems helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the mechanism. I would do it by copy-and-paste.

Comment: @JoWehler I don't think that that'll be good enough for the contributors over there, they're sticklers for not clogging the feed with weak questions, and relative to what they usually go over on that site, this would be a fairly weak question. My reason for posting it here, anyway, was that this is a question about [explanations in mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-explanation/), so since the topic has an entire SEP entry to its name, should be pertinent here.

Comment: I agree that https://mathoverflow.net/ operates on a high level, often a research level. Possibly the level of https://math.stackexchange.com/ fits better. - I do not see the relation of your specific question with the SEP entry from your link.

Comment: @JoWehler *ad hoc* is a description usually (or only?) applied to explanations.

Comment: Math stack exchange is more appropriate the Math Overflow (research-level questions).

Comment: @Annika well, unfortunately for me, years back I asked a bunch of ill-received questions on the MathSE, so despite attempting to improve my reputation there with solid answers to the handful of questions I've since felt competent to address, I still am not in good enough standing to avoid the "don't post any more here" prompt when I think to do so. If my post here could be transferred by votes-to-migrate, I'd be down with that, but having to manually transfer it wouldn't fly.

Comment: @KristianBerry sorry to hear that -- I do think they are overly harsh on sincere questions that are not clearly homework.

Comment: Your posited couniversal set not containing itself if constrained by transitive closure property of all set operations is the famous Grothendieckness G instead of the all encompassing V. It provides a well-defined and structured set for working with large categories of objects and functors (such as schemes and sheaves in AG as fundamental concepts for studying algebraic varieties and other geometric object) while maintaining consistency and avoiding set-theoretic paradoxes. 1st order global choice is not incompatible with amorphous set with the latter conceived as some immanent pan-property...

Comment: It is "*ad hoc*" when taken in isolation. If you can make an independent case for why the class/set distinction is undesirable (beyond "I'd really like to") then it will be legitimate motivation for introducing an option that avoids it. Even better, if it delivers some other benefits. Indeed, even without prior motivation, a case for a theory can be made *ex post facto*. If you can build a fruitful theory around your couniversal set that appeals to intuition and/or has technical advantages over other existing options, etc., that will be good enough. It just shouldn't be a one trick pony.